# Scala class with field that is marked protected in java

Tags: java, scala, jvm

I'm a bit new to scala and trying to test some stuff for my company.
My Problem is the following:
There's a Scala class Test:

```scala
class Test {

  var id: Int = 0

}
```

Doing javap -private -c Test:

```
Compiled from "Test.scala"
public class com.example.Test extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
private int id;

public int id();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield        #11; //Field id:I
   4:   ireturn

public void id_$eq(int);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   iload_1
   2:   putfield        #11; //Field id:I
   5:   return

public com.example.Test();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #19; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   iconst_0
   6:   putfield        #11; //Field id:I
   9:   return

}
```

As you can see, the id variable itself is marked as private. How can I force Scala to mark it as protected? There's really no way round...

Comment: Could you call `id()` and `id_$eq()` methods from your test code? Otherwise, I think the only option is to define the class `Test` in Java. That is, `val` and `var`'s defined in Scala are only available through accessors methods, but Scala can still read/write fields defined in Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the [uniform access principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle), all fields are private in Scala. But the generated methods aren't. So you can do in `Java`:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.id_$eq( 23 );
System.out.println( test.id() ); //Should print "23"
```

If you find it ugly, you can use [Java Beans accessors](http://tomobag.blogspot.com/2008/02/scala-bean-properties.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try writing the class like this:

```
import scala.reflect.BeanProperty

class Test {
  @BeanProperty var id: Int = 0
}
```

Then you'll get a generated `setId` and `getId` methods, as per a "standard" POJO.

Comment: Yes I know :) The problem is this does not help me, because its some jvm bytecode class generation stuff for a database layer which doesn't like fields to be private...

Comment: Then stop using Hibernate :)  Youll find a range of more suitable alternatives here: https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tools+and+Libraries#ToolsandLibraries-DataStorage

Comment: It's not hibernate, but some selfwritten stuff